# Get values from Javascript object

Tags: javascript

I have a Javascript object that looks like this:

```
 Object { .import_236="["100", "200"]"}
```

if I use:

```
{ .import_236="["100", "200"]"}[key][0]
```

It returns me only first character of array...

Comment: It returns the first character because it is not an array, but a string (double quotes). If you want it to be an array, loose the outer double quotes. Also, there are a _lot_ of syntax errors in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can do something like

```
 var obj= { 
   '.import_236':["100", "200"]
}
```

and to access you can use

```
console.log(obj['.import_236'][0])
```

Answer (score 1):

If your object has a name like : myObject = { .import_236="["100", "200"]"}

You can do something like this : myObject['.import_236']. I believe it will return "["100", "200"]"

Hope it Helps